# How to post on friend's wall using facebook API without logging in to facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

After latest Facebook API changes, is there any way to post on friend's wall, using authenticated access_token?

I have tried using [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), but redirects to facebook login page. I want to bypass the login step.

Comment: No, it is not possible to post via API any more to another user’s feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No,You Cant**

Currently, Facebook allows to post by two ways:

1. Using [FacebookAPI](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)
2. Using [Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) (depends on your requirement)

   And in both these methods its must that you should be an **authorised user** to perform the action, **authentication is a must**.So you can't do this without a login.

**NB:** As per the Facebook Developer docs, graph API no longer works .(But I would like to add on that many of the  iOS apps which used this service are still functioning well). So, I prefer to use Facebook SDK.

Hope my answer is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. From the Facebook API documentation on publishing:

"Note: If you are posting to a friend's timeline or wall, you must use the Feed Dialog."

Full details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/